# How can I align textbox and label in a single line

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is my code [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2663fvh/). How can I align textbox and label on one line?

```
<div class="form-style-10">
   <form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
      <input type=hidden name="orgid" value="00D90000000qWA6">
      <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://google.com">

      <div class="inner-wrap">
         <label for="first_name">First Name*</label>
         <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="50" type="text" required />          
      </div>
      <div class="button-section">
         <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a couple different ways you could do it. When they are on the same line, how wide will the input fields be? All the same length? Or will the width be dependent on the label?

Comment: @joshhunt same length would be fine

Comment: I don't have time to make you an example but you might want to look at how Bootstrap do it: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal. Just inspect it using your dev tools. Pretty much use either float or display: inline-box;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set fixed width for label and input and set float left for label

```
.form-style-10 label{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.form-style-10 input[type="text"], .form-style-10 input[type="date"], .form-style-10 input[type="datetime"], .form-style-10 input[type="email"], .form-style-10 input[type="number"], .form-style-10 input[type="search"], .form-style-10 input[type="time"], .form-style-10 input[type="url"], .form-style-10 input[type="password"], .form-style-10 textarea, .form-style-10 select {
    width: 270px;
}
```

Please have a look at the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2663fvh/9/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have width:100% set in your css which is causing it to wrap.  Change the widths to fit the container.

Answer (score 1):

Update the code with following changes

```
.form-style-10 .inner-wrap{
float: left;
}
.form-style-10 label {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}
.form-style-10 input[type="text"], .form-style-10 input[type="date"], .form-style-10 input[type="datetime"], .form-style-10 input[type="email"], .form-style-10 input[type="number"], .form-style-10 input[type="search"], .form-style-10 input[type="time"], .form-style-10 input[type="url"], .form-style-10 input[type="password"], .form-style-10 textarea, .form-style-10 select{
float:left;
width: 80%;
}
```